# JTA - how is transaction registered?

Tags: java, transactions, jta

I am using the following piece of code I found online ([Here](https://access.redhat.com/site/documentation/en-US/JBoss_Enterprise_Application_Platform/6/html/Development_Guide/JTA_Transaction_Example.html)) as an example of JTA Transaction processing:

```
// Get a UserTransaction
        UserTransaction txn = new InitialContext().lookup("java:comp/UserTransaction");
try {
     System.out.println("Starting top-level transaction.");

     txn.begin();
     stmtx = conn.createStatement(); // will be a tx-statement 

     stmtx.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO test_table (a, b) VALUES (1,2)");
     stmtx.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO test_table2 (a, b) VALUES (3,4)");

     System.out.print("\nNow attempting to rollback changes.");

     txn.rollback();
}
```

I have a few questions, in general, about the JTA that are drawn from the example above:

1. I presume the whole point of saying `txn.begin` and then rollback is to be able to (apperently) rollback TWO SQL statements correct?
2. Each of the update queries were TRANSACTIONS themselves, right? They must have succeded so that we can get to rollback call at the bottom. Well, if they succeded i.e. commited, how on earth can we roll them back all of a sudden?
3. The most important question: what happens when we say `txn.begin()`? I understand from the JTA API that it is supposed to register this transaction with a calling thread by `TransactionManager` instance. How is TM even linked to the `UserTransaction`? And finally, how is the txn aware of the fact that we modified the DB twice and is able to speak to DB to roll it back? We have not registered ANY `ResourceManager`s with it so it should not be aware of any resources being at play...

I am a bit lost here, so any info would be appreciated... Question 3 bothers me the most.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. yes, or event just one. It's also the ability of committing the transaction at the end, and thus have the other concurrent transaction only see the new state after the transaction has been committed, and not all the temporary states between the beginning and the end of the transaction (i.e. the I in ACID)
2. No. An update is an update. It's executed as part of the transaction that you begun previously. If one of them doesn't succeed, you'll have an exception, and can still choose to commit the transaction (i.e. have all the previous updates committed), or to rollback the transaction (i.e. have all the previous updates canceled).
3. The UserTransaction has a reference to its transaction manager, presumably. When you get a connection from a DataSource in a Java EE environment, the DataSource is linked to the transaction manager of the Java EE container, and rollbacking the JTA transaction will use the XA protocol to rollback all the operations done on all the data sources during the transaction. That's the container's business, not yours.

Comment: Thanks for your response @JB Nizet. I need to disagree on the 2-nd point. If I did not use the JTA at all, I would simply use a JDBC, execute the two queries (default autoCommit is true) and subsequently checked the DB I would find it to be updated. This is just a simple JDBC query which updates the DB and underneath behaves a single transaction (two separate transactions, in this case as we have executed two SQL statements)

Comment: auto-commit is false when using a JTA transaction, obviously. So no, they're not transactions. If they were transactions, each update would be committed right after it's executed, and you wouldn't be able to rollback them anymore, defeating the whole purpose of using a transaction.

Answer (score 1):

There's a lot to learn about transactions, but maybe I can give you a head start:

1. Yes. But you will usually only want to rollback in case of a problem - some step of the transaction could not be completed because of a technical issue (syntax error, table not found, segment overrun, ...) or an application logic problem (customer has not enough funds for all order line items for example).
2. Given auto commit mode is disabled, the inserts are not committed before you actually commit. They are temporarily applied to the database using a Write-Ahead-Log (PostgreSQL, InnoDB-Engine, Oracle) with sophisticated Multi-Version-Concurrency-Control (MVCC) which determines which state of the database each transactional client can see. A very interesting topic :-).
3. A UserTransaction is registered with your current Thread. Resources (i.e. Databases or Messaging services) enlist themselves with the UserTransaction. This is usually only necessary when you are using distributed transactions (XA transactions, 2PC).

I suggest to get a good read on SQL programming (for example [Head First SQL](http://www.headfirstlabs.com/books/hfsql/)) and check out the [Java EE 6 tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/).

Comment: Thanks for your answers. I still do not see how the UserTransaction knows anything about the underlying DBConnection. How would the connection (DB resource) enlist itself within the UserTransaction? UserTransaction does not even expose a mechanism like this via the API

Comment: It is a good thing that you want to know that stuff, I like that :)! 

The 'magic' that bothers you is described in the [JTA specification](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javaee/tech/jta-138684.html):
---
3.2.1 Starting a Transaction
The TransactionManager.begin
method starts a global transaction and associates
the transaction context with the calling thread.
---
(Section 3.3.1 Resource Enlistment)
"Resource enlistment performed by an application server serves two purposes:
It informs the Transaction Manager about the resouce manager instance that is
participating in the global...

Comment: Sorry, I still have to learn the formatting options for comments - basically have a look at the JTA spec and app server source code. Have fun!

Comment: Thanks again for your comments. I get the idea that using TransactionManager we get a Transaction object, for which we can enlist the resource via calling enlistResource(XAResource) method. However, UserTransactions is not governed by the transactionManager i.e. it does not begin by making a call to TransactionManager... That's why I am a bit confused.